# Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1

Tags: java, netty

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1 (file:/D:/eclipse_workspace/Server_GameBox/lib/netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release。
```

this is my question.I am first use stackoverflow, I don't know how to use it.
but I hope some people can help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it is your first time, you will find plenty of advice if you start of by taking [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One of the first things anyone will ask you is to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that was causing your problem. Posting just an error message without making it clear what you did that caused that error will make it very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Also, you don't actually have a question in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest 4.1 release of netty. This was fixed a long time ago, and your version of netty is very old.

Comment: `4.1.58` and `4.1.59.Final` has the same warning

Comment: However, `--illegal-access=warn` VM parameter hides it.